# Elasticsearch-py bulk helper equivalent of curl with file

Tags: python-3.x, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am looking to replicate the following command using the elasticsearch python client (and without using `subprocess`):

```shell
curl -s -XPOST "localhost:9200/index_name/_bulk" --data-binary @file
```

I have attempted to use the bulk helper without any luck:

```python
es = Elasticsearch()

with open("file") as fp:
    bulk(
        client=es,
        index="index_name",
        actions=fp
    )
```

This results in `type is missing` errors.

The file, which is processed just fine when using `curl`, looks a bit like this:

```
{"index":{"_type":"someType","_id":"123"}}
{"field1":"data","field2":"data",...}
{"index":{"_type":"someType","_id":"456"}}
{"field1":"data","field2":"data",...}
...
```

Please note, I'd rather not change the contents of the file since I have around 21000 with the same format.

Answer (score 0):

The `actions` parameter must take an iterable (not a file handle) that will iterate over the lines of your file, so you need to do it like this instead:

```
es = Elasticsearch()

def readbulk():
    for line in open("file"):
        yield line

bulk(
    client=es,
    index="index_name",
    actions=readbulk
)
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `readbulk`? Omitting `()` will result in `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`. File handles have `__iter__` and `__next__` methods so, as expected, using this generator did not make a difference. Still, thank you for responding.